# The '.' operator on null nullable

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, null, nullable

How is it that you can access **null** nullable's propery `HasValue`?
I looked to the compiled code, and it's not a syntactic sugar.

Why this doesn't throw NullReferenceException:

```
int? x = null;
if (x.HasValue)
{...}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because `int?` is short for [`Nullable<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) which is a value type, not a reference type - so you will never get a  `NullReferenceException`.

The `Nullable<T>` struct looks something like this:

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
{
    private readonly T value;
    private readonly bool hasValue;
    //..
}
```

When you assign `null` there is some magic happening with support by the compiler (which knows about `Nullable<T>` and treats them special in this way) which just sets the `hasValue` field to false for this instance - which is then returned by the `HasValue` property.

Comment: Addition, struct never assigned null.

Answer (score 1):

Like [BrokenGlass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8380024/740923) said, an `int?` is actually a `Nullable<T>`.

Structures always contain a value.  Usually you cannot set a structure variable to null, but in this special case you can, essentially setting it to `default(Nullable<T>)`.  This sets its contents to null rather than the variable itself.

When you set a `Nullable<T>` to a value, it uses an implicit operator to set `Value = value` to the new value and `HasValue = true`.

When you set `Nullable<T>` to null, it nulls all of the structure's fields.  For a `bool` field such as `HasValue`, `null == false`.

Since a `Nullable<T>` variable is a structure, the variable can always be referenced because its contents is null rather than the variable itself.

There's more information on structures in the Remarks section of the MSDN page [struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: "Setting a structure variable to null sets its contents to null rather than the variable itself." This is wrong - you cannot assign `null` to a value type/struct - with the exception of `Nullable<T>` which the compiler will translate appropriately to setting the `hasValue` field to false. This is only possible because the compiler knows about `Nullable<T>`, hence the "magic" comment.

Comment: @BrokenGlass, you're right.  I'm used to VB.Net and am currently teaching myself C#.  In VB you can assign `Dim x As SomeStructure = Nothing`.  I'm guessing this is the same as `SomeStructure x = default(SomeStructure)` rather than `SomeStructure x = null`.

Comment: @gdoron, tricky, given my answer is fundamentally wrong, but I'll give it a shot.  :-)